# Assert a function/method was not called using Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm using the Mock library to test my application, but I want to assert that some function was not called. Mock docs talk about methods like `mock.assert_called_with` and `mock.assert_called_once_with`, but I didn't find anything like `mock.assert_not_called` or something related to verify mock was **NOT called**.

I could go with something like the following, though it doesn't seem cool nor pythonic:

```
def test_something:
    # some actions
    with patch('something') as my_var:
        try:
            # args are not important. func should never be called in this test
            my_var.assert_called_with(some, args)
        except AssertionError:
            pass  # this error being raised means it's ok
    # other stuff
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: As @Ahmet points out in his answer, assert_not_called is now supported, also in the backport (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_not_called).

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This should work for your case;

```
assert not my_var.called, 'method should not have been called'
```

Sample;

```
>>> mock=Mock()
>>> mock.a()
<Mock name='mock.a()' id='4349129872'>
>>> assert not mock.b.called, 'b was called and should not have been'
>>> assert not mock.a.called, 'a was called and should not have been'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: a was called and should not have been
```

Comment: Does this answer require Django? I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: MockCallable instance has no attribute 'called'`

Comment: @NathanArthur Hm, I don't think so, after `sudo easy_install -U mock` and `from mock import Mock` on MacOS, the above runs without a hitch. Never installed Django :)

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. I'm running Python 2.7.1 and am using unittest and `from mock import Mock` with Python Mock 0.1.0 for my tests. Does any of that sound problematic?

Comment: I'm mocking a callable class from another module, so it looks like `module_to_test.another_module.class = mock.Mock()`, can you confirm this doesn't remember calls across different test cases (unittest.TestCase instances)? I think the call count doesn't reset in this case

Comment: Use assert_not_called method

Answer (score 113):

Though an old question, I would like to add that currently `mock` library (backport of unittest.mock) supports `assert_not_called` method.

Just upgrade yours;

`pip install mock --upgrade`

Answer (score 47):

With `python >= 3.5` you can use `mock_object.assert_not_called()`.

Answer (score 32):

You can check the `called` attribute, but if your assertion fails, the next thing you'll want to know is something *about* the unexpected call, so you may as well arrange for that information to be displayed from the start. Using `unittest`, you can check the contents of `call_args_list` instead:

```
self.assertItemsEqual(my_var.call_args_list, [])
```

When it fails, it gives a message like this:

```
AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
First has 0, Second has 1:  call('first argument', 4)
```

Answer (score 20):

When you test using class inherits **unittest.TestCase** you can simply use methods like:

- assertTrue
- assertFalse
- assertEqual

and similar (in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.debug) you find the rest).

In your example we can simply assert if **mock_method.called** property is ***False***, which means that method was not called.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import my_module

class A(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.message = "Method should not be called. Called {times} times!"

    @mock.patch("my_module.method_to_mock")
    def test(self, mock_method):
        my_module.method_to_mock()

        self.assertFalse(mock_method.called,
                         self.message.format(times=mock_method.call_count))
```

Comment: I cannot understand why this answer has so few votes.... to me, this is the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from other answers, no one except [@rob-kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432369/2219670) talked about the `call_args_list`.

It's a powerful tool for that you can implement the exact contrary of `MagicMock.assert_called_with()`

`call_args_list` is a list of `call` objects. Each `call` object represents a call made on a mocked callable.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m.call_args_list
[]
>>> m(42)
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139675158423872'>
>>> m.call_args_list
[call(42)]
>>> m(42, 30)
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139675158423872'>
>>> m.call_args_list
[call(42), call(42, 30)]
```

Consuming a `call` object is easy, since you can compare it with a tuple of length 2 where the first component is a tuple containing all the positional arguments of the related call, while the second component is a dictionary of the keyword arguments.

```
>>> ((42,),) in m.call_args_list
True
>>> m(42, foo='bar')
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139675158423872'>
>>> ((42,), {'foo': 'bar'}) in m.call_args_list
True
>>> m(foo='bar')
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139675158423872'>
>>> ((), {'foo': 'bar'}) in m.call_args_list
True
```

So, a way to address the specific problem of the OP is

```
def test_something():
    with patch('something') as my_var:
        assert ((some, args),) not in my_var.call_args_list
```

Note that this way, instead of just checking if a mocked callable has been called, via `MagicMock.called`, you can now check if it has been called with a specific set of arguments.

That's useful. Say you want to test a function that takes a list and call another function, `compute()`, for each of the value of the list only if they satisfy a specific condition.

You can now mock `compute`, and test if it has been called on some value but not on others.

Answer (score -1):

My preferred idiom for checking that a mock was called/not called is as follows:
`self.assertEqual(post_mock.call_count, 0)`

Benefits:

1. Making sure that the mock was called/not called the correct number of times.
2. Using the internal PyTest [assertEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) function.