# Python 2.7 mock/patch: understanding assert_called_XYZ()

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I'm relatively new to Python and unit testing in Python. From the Java world I know the concept of mocking but it seem to be much different from what I can see in Python.

I found this guide, which I found very helpful: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html

But as I wrote my (a bit more complex) tests with mocked out dependencies I noticed a strage behavior.
I decided to create a reduced, simple example which also does not work as I expect it.

Take a look at this, the result and my expectation I have added as comments:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock

class BasicTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("StringIO.StringIO")
    def testSomethingNotWorkingAsExpected(self, StringIOMock):
        StringIOMock.assert_called_once() # asserts, but why?

    @patch("StringIO.StringIO")
    def testSomethingSomehowWorking(self, StringIOMock):
        # self.instantiateStringIO() # intentionally commented out
        assert StringIOMock.called # does not assert (leading to failure of this test); as expected. If the above line is not commented, this asserts as expected.

    def instantiateStringIO(self):
        import StringIO
        StringIO.StringIO()
```

Why is `assert_called_once()` asserting the instantiation of `StringIO` even it has not been instantiated yet?
And why does `assert ClassMock.called` bring the expected results?

Using `assert not ...` to assert a method has not been called I found here: [Assert a function/method was not called using Mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187122/assert-a-function-method-was-not-called-using-mocking). I inverted this pattern in my case by omitting the `not`.

Somewhere I found the pattern `ClassMock.return_value` to reference an instance. But I understand this as a way to manupulate the instance of a Mock before it will be called, not as a way to access the instance that might an underliing code have internally created. Or am I wrong?

My environment:

- Python 2.7.3
- mock 0.8.8
- Fedora 19

Probably my understanding of the mock/patch thing is wrong. Could please someone aditionally explain what a class mock does and how it works?

## Edit1: Added output

... and added paraphrase in parens to comment in `testSomethingSomehowWorking`

This is the output:

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: testSomethingSomehowWorking (test_test.BasicTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1224, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "test_test.py", line 15, in testSomethingSomehowWorking
    assert StringIOMock.called # does not assert; as expected
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: When I uncomment the `self.instantiateStringIO()` both tests pass for me.

Comment: Yes they will, but this is not what I expect. But I guess you've found the problem as I can see from your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method `assert_called_once` does not exist and it does not perform an assertion. It's no different from writing `StringIOMock.assert_foo_bar_does_not_exist()` or any other method. The mock library doesn't check whether the method called on the mock actually exists.

If you use [`assert_called_once_with`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) then it fails as expected.

You can use the `spec` parameter to raise an error when you call a non-existent method:

```
@patch("StringIO.StringIO", spec=StringIO.StringIO)
def testSomethingNotWorkingAsExpected(self, StringIOMock):
    StringIOMock.assert_called_once() # will fail as the method doesn't exist
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that undefined methods called on a Mock will be ignored (calling undefined methods on normal instances usually lead to an error). I suspected this, but were unable to find it. I somewhere found `assert_called_once()` because I was looking for a assertion method that ignores the parameters. It was obviously incorrect. Thanks for solving this.